# Offset of type in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'd like to know if it's possible to find the offset of a structure in an object with multiple inheritance **without** knowing any members of any type. I **do** know the types, if that helps.

I'm currently calculating offsets using `sizeof()`. Problems exist when I have an empty base class, or padding is added when combining two classes for multiple inheritance.

Let me show the problem using an example:

```
struct A { int x; };
struct B { bool b; }; // Empty struct gives same results
struct C : B, A {};

int main()
{
    // Prints: 4 1 8
    printf("%i %i %i\n", sizeof(A), sizeof(B), sizeof(C));

    C obj;
    obj.x = 1;
    obj.b = true;

    // Simple offset calculations, I can't use these because they both use data members
    // Prints: 4 4
    printf("%i %i\n", (int)&obj.x - (int)&obj, offsetof(C, x));

    // Cast to pointer
    char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&obj);
    A* wrong = reinterpret_cast<A*>(ptr + sizeof(B));

    // Prints wrong values because sizeof(B) == 1 wrongly offsets the pointer
    printf("%i\n", wrong->x);

    // Because of padding this is correct
    // Empty base class optimization would simply cast ptr as correct
    // How to get the correct offset?
    A* correct = reinterpret_cast<A*>(ptr + 4);

    // Prints correct value, 1
    printf("%i\n", correct->x);
}
```

Comment: `%zu` is the format specifier for `sizeof` in printf

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but maybe `reinterpret_cast<char *>(static_cast<A *>(&obj)) - reinterpret_cast<char *>(&obj);`

Comment: Note that if virtual inheritance is involved, there's no good way to do this at all.

Comment: `static_cast` can be used to acquire a pointe to the base class. The offset can then be calculated by looking at the difference between base and child pointer.

Comment: Virtual inheritance is not involved. No vtables. So, the solution of M.M is perfectly fine in my case. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Does the standard `offsetof` macro not provide this functionality?

Comment: @JackO'Reilly - `offsetof` only works for for standard-layout types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
reinterpret_cast<char *>(static_cast<A *>(&obj)) - reinterpret_cast<char *>(&obj);
```